# How to combine the \circled command on one-digit numbers and the \newcircled commands on two-digit numbers?

Tags: numbering, diagrams, conditionals

First a MWE and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%define circled command%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=0.3pt,text depth=0pt,font=\normalfont,minimum size=6pt] (char) {#1};}
%%%define newcircled command%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphics}
\newcommand*\newcircled[1]{\circled{\textls[-70]{\scalebox{0.53}[1]{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
We have circled one-digit numbers and two-digit numbers by the \verb|\circled| command as follows.
\begin{center}
\circled{0} \circled{1} \circled{2} \circled{3} \circled{4} \circled{5} \circled{6} \circled{7} \circled{8} \circled{9}  \circled{10} \circled{11} \circled{12} \circled{23} \circled{68}
\end{center}
And we also have circled one-digit numbers by the \verb|\circled| command and two-digit numbers by the \verb|\newcircled| command as follows which are as desired.
\begin{center}
\circled{0} \circled{1} \circled{2} \circled{3} \circled{4} \circled{5} \circled{6} \circled{7} \circled{8} \circled{9}  \newcircled{10} \newcircled{11} \newcircled{12} \newcircled{23} \newcircled{68}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Clearly the second line of numbers are as desried. So my question is **how to combine the `\circled` and \newcircled commands on numbers** or **how to produce a command which atomically uses the `\circled` command on one-digit numbers and the `\newcircled` command on two-digit numbers**？

---

---

> After @CarLaTeX 's answer, we can have **excellent circled numbers
> with two-digits for footnotes**, which maybe the best so far as now.
> The following is an MWE and its output. Note that you could use
> `LaTeX` or `PDFLaTeX` but not `XeTeX` or `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX` to
> compile the file since the `microtype` package can't be used in
> `XeTeX` or `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`. To use `XeTeX` or `XeLaTeX` or
> `LuaLaTeX` to compile the file, you can use the `fontspec` package and
> the `\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=-9.0}` command instead (Cf. [the
> third solution here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/639378/140814)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphics}%for \scalebox
\usepackage{etoolbox}%for \ifnumcomp
\usepackage{microtype}%for \textls
%%%define circled command%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{circlednode/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    inner sep=0.1ex,
    text depth=0ex,
    font=\normalfont,
    minimum size=1ex
    }
}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
    \ifnumcomp{#1}{>}{9}{% 
        % if > 9:
        \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[circlednode] (char) {\textls[-70]{\scalebox{0.53}[1]{#1}}};}{%
        % if <= 9: 
        \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[circlednode] (char) {#1};}%
    }
%%%footnote number setting%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
%make footnote numbers be circled------------------
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{%
    \raisebox{0.25ex}{%
    \scalebox{0.7}{\protect\circled{%
            \arabic{footnote}}%
        }%
    }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
We have circled one-digit numbers and two-digit numbers by the \verb|\circled| command as follows.
\begin{center}
\circled{0} \circled{1} \circled{2} \circled{3} \circled{4} \circled{5} \circled{6} \circled{7} \circled{8} \circled{9}  \circled{10} \circled{11} \circled{12} \circled{23} \circled{68}
\end{center}
\par We can also produce excellent circled numbers with two-digits for footnotes with the help of the \verb|\circled| command, which maybe the best so far as now. 
\par Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}.Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test}. Now we test the footnote numbers with two digits\footnote{Test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test.}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\ifnumcomp` from `etoolbox` to test if the number is greater than 9:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    inner sep=0.3pt,
    text depth=0pt,
    font=\normalfont,
    minimum size=6pt
    }
}
%%%define circled command%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
    \ifnumcomp{#1}{>}{9}{% 
        % if > 9:
        \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[mynode] (char) {\textls[-70]{\scalebox{0.53}[1]{#1}}};}{%
        % if <= 9: 
        \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[mynode] (char) {#1};}%
    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
We have circled one-digit numbers and two-digit numbers by the \verb|\circled| command as follows.
\begin{center}
\circled{0} \circled{1} \circled{2} \circled{3} \circled{4} \circled{5} \circled{6} \circled{7} \circled{8} \circled{9}  \circled{10} \circled{11} \circled{12} \circled{23} \circled{68}
\end{center}
And we also have circled one-digit numbers by the \verb|\circled| command and two-digit numbers by the \verb|\circled| command as follows which are as desired.
\begin{center}
\circled{0} \circled{1} \circled{2} \circled{3} \circled{4} \circled{5} \circled{6} \circled{7} \circled{8} \circled{9}  \circled{10} \circled{11} \circled{12} \circled{23} \circled{68}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer! Now in this way we can have excellent circled numbers with two-digits for **footnotes**, which maybe the best so far as now. I will post that in the final of my question.

Comment: I also post the solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/639370/140814

Comment: By the way, what's your real name? I'd like to show thanks to people who help me a lot on Latex when writing my book.

Comment: @M.Logic I don't like to put my real name on the internet but you can find it [here](https://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/listauthor.html#Maggi,Carla)

Comment: I got it. By the way, how to pronounce your surname?

Comment: @M.Logic mʌdʒdʒɪ

Comment: Are there two dʒ sounds?

Comment: @M.Logic I don't know how to write that the "g" is double :D

Comment: @M.Logic Reading your link, I think the correct one is this: Pronunciation
IPA(key): /ˈmad.d͡ʒi/  (See the section "Italian")